# What is the correct event for collecting/updating order information after order success?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, event-observer

I've seen multiple people use `save_order_place_after`, as well as `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.  My issue is that I want to do a quick scan of information collected on that order, and update tables depending on the information collected. I've tried both of these events and get the following results (using PayPal Onepage checkout):

`save_order_place_after`:

- Blank page loaded (PayPal payment review page according to URL)
- Order interrupted (no success page)
- Payment is sent to PayPal successfully
- No order information is saved anywhere in admin panel or database
- Account then becomes glitched with "duplicate invoice" error and cannot place another order without receiving error
- An email is triggered and sent successfully from the `Observer.php`

`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`:

- Order is successful
- Success page loaded
- Nothing is executed from `Observer.php`

There are no syntax errors in the `Observer.php`, as it works correctly with the first event but is apparently interrupting the order in some way.

Is there another event that's triggered after an order is successfully completed and saved so that I can scan all information collected on the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only ever had success with `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

```xml
       <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <googleanalytics_order_success>
                        <class>googleanalytics/observer</class>
                        <method>setGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageView</method>
                    </googleanalytics_order_success>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <googleanalytics_order_success>
                        <class>googleanalytics/observer</class>
                        <method>setGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageView</method>
                    </googleanalytics_order_success>
                </observers>
            </checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action>
        </events>
```

I've updated my observer logic.  I think what you've used is the problem.

Observer looks like this

Model/Observer.php

```php
class Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function setGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
            return;
        }
        // $orderIds is array   
        // do stuff
        foreach($orderIds as $orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            // stuff
        }

        // or
        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds));
        foreach($orders as $order) {
            // stuff
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason I can think of that might cause this event to not work for me is that it might not be grabbing the order ID correctly for some reason? Shouldn't `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();` work just fine when using this event?

Comment: @taskle I think that might be where you've gone wrong.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'll have to try this way, but I'm confused as to why this event would require getting the order through a collection loop whereas `sales_save_place_after` you can get the order by itself.

Comment: @taskle yep it's how magento works in this case

Comment: When do orders have multiple order IDs?

Comment: It's not a feature I've ever used but I believe orders with reoccurring payments, multishipping or an enterprise feature I don't know about that's made it's way into community edition

Comment: @taskle How did you get on with my example? Did you achieve the results you were after?  Please accept my answer if it works.

Comment: This has worked for me, with the exception of setting the order to a new `state` and `status`, which I'm sure is another issue. My email dispatching does work and the success page loads just fine.  (By the way, `$orders = $Mage::getModel` has an un-needed `$` on the `$Mage`)